# How to kill eventListener on XmlHttpRequest network calls

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, addeventlistener, removeeventlistener

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    var oldXHR, stateChangeHandler, statusChange, prop;
    oldXHR = window.XMLHttpRequest;
    window.top.globalVariable = 0;
    window.top.globalVariables = {};
    stateChangeHandler = function(event) {
        if (this.readyState === oldXHR.DONE) {
            var id_st = this._id;
            delete window.top.globalVariables[id_st];
            window.top.globalVariable = count(window.top.globalVariables);
        } else {
            var id_st = this._id;
            window.top.globalVariables[id_st] = 1;
            var c = count(window.top.globalVariables);
            if (window.top.globalVariable > c) {
                window.top.globalVariable = c;
            }
        }
    };

    function count(p) {
        var len = 0;
        for (var key in p) {
            if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                len++
            }
        }
        return len
    }

    function newXHR() {
        var xhr = new oldXHR();
        xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', stateChangeHandler);
        if (xhr.status === 0) {
            window.top.globalVariable++;
        }
        return xhr
    }
    for (prop in oldXHR) {
        newXHR[prop] = oldXHR[prop]
    }
    window.XMLHttpRequest = newXHR
})();
```

This js script is being injected to browser from selenium code for automation. This code snippet tracks the state of xhr network calls and checks if the state of this call is ready or not. It keeps the count of such xhr request calls which are still loading.

Now i need to detach this eventListener but my approach should be injecting one more js script from which i would be removing this eventListener.

I have used window.XmlHttpRequest.removeEventListener('readystatechange', stateChangeHandler); but it fails to recognise stateChangeHandler, may be because of variable scope. Then i changed it to window.stateChangehandler but still didn't worked out.

So, please help me out.

Comment: There's nothing you can do from outside, after the anonymous function has been executed. Listeners are attached to instances of XMLHttpRequest, not to the constructor (which the function also overrides).

Comment: Any change in this js script, that could help ?

Comment: If you can execute a script before this, you can get a reference to the original XMLHttpRequest, and use that instead of the Selenium overridden constructor when you're creating AJAX calls. If you can change this script, just remove the listener from the code.